# How to trim column values without turning them into strings?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm looking for a method to trim the cells of a dataset, in order to clean it, but methods such as trim() end up casting integers as string. Is there a way to ensure there are no empty spaces in my data without changing the data type?

```
def clean_data(df):
    for c in df.columns: 
        df = df.withColumn(c, trim(col(c))) 
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your data is actually in string format, that's why you have `whitespaces`. So if you cast that data in a `int`, you should be fine.

```py
df = int(df.withColumn(c, trim(col(c))))
```

Comment: Some of it is in string format and some of it is float.